# Calling method from another class - Error: constructor Customer in class Customer cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I'm trying to adjust the code in the Store class's richestCustomer() method to make use of the hasMoreMoneyThan() method, but I keep getting the error 'constructor Customer in class Customer cannot be applied to given types'

Does anyone know how to fix this?

CUSTOMER CLASS:

```
public class Customer {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private float money;
  public Customer(String n, int a, float m) {
    name = n;
    age = a;
    money = m;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return "Customer " + name + ": a " + age + " year old with $" + money;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
  public int getAge(){
    return age;
  }

  public boolean hasMoreMoneyThan(Customer c){
    if(this.money > c.money){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

STORE CLASS:

```
public class Store {
  public static final int MAX_CUSTOMERS = 500;
  String name;
  Customer[] customers;
  int customerCount;
  public Store(String n) {
    name = n;
    customers = new Customer[MAX_CUSTOMERS];
    customerCount = 0;
  }
  public void addCustomer(Customer c) {
    if (customerCount < MAX_CUSTOMERS)
      customers[customerCount++] = c;
  }
  public void listCustomers() {
    for (int i=0; i<customerCount; i++)
      System.out.println(customers[i]);
  }
  public int averageCustomerAge(){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < customerCount; i++){
      sum += customers[i].getAge();
    }
    int averageAge = sum/customerCount;
    return averageAge;
  }

  public Customer richestCustomer(){
    Customer richest = new Customer();
    for(int i = 0; i < customerCount; i++){
      if(customers[i].hasMoreMoneyThan(richest)){
        richest = customers[i];
      }
    }
    return richest;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a custom constructor in class, default constructor no more included by default in the class, you need to explicitly define it.
Either define default constructor in your Customer class or use the one which you have defined by passing the default values.

`Customer richest = new Customer(null, 0, 0f);`

A better implementation of your method will be to assume the first customer as richest and compare with the rest:

```
public Customer richestCustomer(){
    if(customerCount <= 0) {
        return null; // or throw exception
    }
    Customer richest = customers[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < customerCount; i++){
        if(customers[i].hasMoreMoneyThan(richest)){
            richest = customers[i];
        }
    }
    return richest;
}
```